# How are Android sensor TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION and TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR implemented?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, android-hardware, sensor-fusion

I have been searching for quiet some time for the algorithm used by the Android API to fuse raw data from different sensors to produce virtual sensors.

How have they been implemented?
Is the source code available somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the source code available somewhere?

Unfortunately, the Fused Location Provider API is not a part of the Android Open Source Project but rather it's implemented as a part of Google Play Services which is a proprietary Google software and it's source code is not publicly available. In fact, the `FusedLocationProviderApi.java` interface implementations are purposedly obfuscated, for example:

```
public class zzd implements FusedLocationProviderApi {
    public zzd() {
    }

    public Location getLastLocation(GoogleApiClient var1) {
        zzl var2 = LocationServices.zzj(var1);

        try {
            return var2.getLastLocation();
        } catch (Exception var4) {
            return null;
        }
    }
...
```

> How have they been implemented?

Since the source is not available, we may only speculate on how exactly it's implemented.

Answer (score -3):

You have to get an instance of the sensor manager

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
  ...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

After that you can access the accelerometer data like this:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
  // In this example, alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT),
  // where t is the low-pass filter's time-constant and
  // dT is the event delivery rate.

  final float alpha = 0.8;

  // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
  gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
  gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
  gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

  // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
  linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
  linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
  linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
}
```

For more information read the [developer.android Page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel)